# Creating a new dictionary from a dictionary with multiple values per key

Tags: dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this basically

```
d = {'book1': [('chapverse1', 'verse1'),('chapverse2','verse2')]
     'book2': [('chapverse1', 'verse1'),('chapverse2','verse2')]}
```

What I need to do is create a second dictionary from the values inside based on the book it is in.
Something like:

```
read through d
if book is in d
```

create `newdict` with values from that book.

any help would be greatly appreciated.
This is in Python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well it's unclear what you want to do, but I'll try to guess:

```
>>> d = {
      'book1': [('chapverse1', 'verse1'),('chapverse2','verse2')],
      'book2': [('chapverse1', 'verse1'),('chapverse2','verse2')]
    }
>>> d2 = {k: dict(v) for k, v in d.items()}
>>> d2
{
    'book1': {'chapverse1': 'verse1', 'chapverse2': 'verse2'},
    'book2': {'chapverse1': 'verse1', 'chapverse2': 'verse2'}
}
```

**edit:**

```
>>> book = 'book2'
>>> book_dict = dict(d['book2'])
>>> book_dict
{'chapverse1': 'verse1', 'chapverse2': 'verse2'}
```

Comment: Sorry for not making it clear enough I have been messing with this for a while and my mind is hazy. basically the user will pic a book and I want to make a new dictionary from just that one book. so that I can print out specific verses.